# IMPORTXML not pulling required data to Google Sheets

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, blockchain

I'm attempting to pull data from a blockchain explorer:

http://explorer.birake.com/

In my attempt at feeding to Google Sheets the number of 'Master Nodes' live, I am using the function:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://explorer.birake.com/","//div[@id='masternodepanel']")
```

Instead of returning an integer, it is returning `-`.

I see from the Inspect tool that the number is contained within the label id "masternodeCountOnline", however, cannot successfully parse this information through `IMPORTXML`.

Can someone assist with this to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

**not possible to scrape. all you can get is what you see here:**

[image: 0]

Comment: Can you think of any other method to pull this data? Another function maybe?

Comment: this is not about function, it's about the site itself which is controlled by JavaScript and therefore it can't be scrapped. more about scraping here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126329/186471